Is quantum entanglement independent of measurement timing?
If I have the entangled state
$\vert \uparrow \downarrow \rangle + \vert  \downarrow \uparrow\rangle$, and then
measure the spin of one particle and find it to be $\uparrow$, will the spin of the second particle be measured as $\downarrow$ , regardless of whether I measure it immediately after the first measurement or much later?
Is quantum entanglement independent of measurement time or particle states are correlated only for simultaneous measurement?

What do you mean? What does "opposite" mean? Have you tried a simple example? It should be evident from the formulation of quantum mechanics.

Regarding your edit: As I said above, please write down equations, define your things and then the problem, and a possible solutions, becomes much clearer.

It’s ridiculous because if you’ve gone to the trouble of preparing two particles to have opposite spins, then obviously they have opposite spins! Why even test them if you already know the outcome? And if you didn’t get the spins perfectly matched as opposites, there’s no point in running the experiment at all.

@BillAlsept If you prepare opposite spins in synchronization, if you delay with second meassurement, you wont get always opposite spin...

@22flower You're focusing on linear dependency, which can cause timing issues when particles are oscillating, rotating, or shifting through phases as they move. But when it comes to polarization or spin axis, those stay constant, so the timing of your measurement wouldn't affect the outcome. If your talking about photon pairs which do have frequencies, then yes the distance/timing needs to be within 1/2 wavelength or the result will be skewed.

Yes, if you measure one of the spins as $\uparrow$, for instance, then the state of the other spin will be $\downarrow$ immediately. Entanglement is a property of the state itself, and thus has no relation to the amount of time between the measurement of one particle and the other (as long as nothing perturbs the second particle in the mean time, of course).
A nice presentation of these states can be found in the book Quantum Computation And Quantum Information, by Michael A. Nielsen and Isaac L. Chuang.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


According to relativity of simultaneously, when 2 events are space-like separated (they are too far to send signal to each other), if they are simultaneous in one observer point of view, you can always find another observer who claims that those two events are not simultaneous. In fact, the time order of the events becomes arbitrary. If you say S1 measured first, then S2, I might say no S2 measured first and then S1, and I am completely right, as far as SR is concerned.

So your question is somewhat meaningless without specifying from whose point of view are we talking about.

Now let's say S1 measures the state of their particle and $|\downarrow\rangle$, and we want to know from their point of view, whether the second particle at S2 needs to be measured simultaneously to get $|\uparrow\rangle$ or not.

The answer is, it depends on the Hamiltonian. If both $|\downarrow\rangle$ and  $|\uparrow\rangle$ are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, it does not matter when S2 measurment is conducted. However, it would matter if they are not eigenstates, as after S1 measurement Hamiltonian might change $|\uparrow\rangle$  to any other state in the hilbert space and S2 would not observe $|\uparrow\rangle$ because of that.
Edit: Please enlighten my ignorance by telling me why I am wrong after downvoting, thank you.

I don't think this helps the OP at all, this mixes several concepts that do not make the answer clear. It is not even known how robust entanglement is to a boost, there are studies that claim that the state itself changes and loses entanglement, changing completely the picture. For me, the question is on whether delaying the second measurement matters or not for entanglement, to which your answer does not address

@FranklinLuis Thank you. But how do we talk about "simultaneous measurement" without specifying an observer first? What is simultaneous in your point of view?

You also don't need to be passive aggressive with my downvote, this does not mean that you're ignorant, just that I do not agree with the answer...
And I take a finite time to write, or perhaps I even finished this simultaneously for some observer ;)

@FranklinLuis Everybody makes mistakes. Sometimes down votes are due to conceptual mistakes, and the person wouldn't realize why they are wrong without an extra comment, which is why I asked for it. It is all good.

Yes, special relativity describes the reality of our world, but we can talk about quantum without resorting to such complicated arguments, the spins could be stationary and close by, for instance. How can a band play harmonically together, if for some observer the bass will be completely out of rhythm with respect to the drums?

All good bro, I understood it bad

@FranklinLuis which studies claim the entanglement can be lost due to a boost?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2223
If you consider only the spin degree of freedom, entanglement is dependent on the observer. One would have to take the momentum space into consideration in order to recover the initial correlation. This in flat spacetime, in curved spacetime even this property is lost.

Without specifically disagreeing with either of the answers of Franklin or Paradoxy, there are a few clarifications that need to be made.
Most important: The order of measurements on components of an entangled pair makes NO OBSERVABLE difference at all.  Further, you cannot make a statement about an unobserved particle prior to its observation.  The ENTIRE measurement context must be known.  The consequences are as follows:
a. You cannot apply Special Relativity in any manner to determine the quantum expectation value.  There are no reference frames in which that value changes.
b. You cannot assert that the value of the unmeasured component of the entangled pair has any particular value unless you measure it on that basis.  The argument that you could assert that is in fact the original EPR argument (1935).  Of course, we know today that is wrong (due to Bell and others).
c. And in fact entangled pairs can and are created every day that have either or both of these attributes: i) they never co-exist; ii) they are entangled AFTER they are measured.  Clearly, if they are entangled after the fact, how can they already have specific values prior to their measurement?  The entire context must be examined, not just portions of the context.  If needed, I can provide experimental references in addition to the following:
High-fidelity entanglement swapping with fully independent sources
With these provisos, the answers are:
YES to the original question: "Is quantum entanglement independent of measurement time?..."
YES to the original question: "...will the spin of the second particle be measured as ↓ , regardless of whether I measure it immediately after the first measurement or much later?"  But ONLY if it is actually measured on the same basis, and definitely NOT otherwise.

(+1) Does point C "if they are entangled after... how can they already have specific values prior to their measurement" refer to the delayed choice eraser type experiments? If so, then by special relativity there should be a certain frame of reference when the order of events is reversed, i.e. the entanglement is done before the particles are measured, right? Then, by point A " there is no reference frames in which that value changes", it seems there is nothing weirdly time-paradoxical about this phenomena?

@James You can perform experiments such that the event order is the same in all reference frames - or appears reversed (!) as you say. For example: In a delayed choice experiment, the choice can be performed long after the other components are detected. 2 photons start off 1 nanosecond apart, and are measured 1 ns later. The delayed choice is performed 10 ns later, so order is fixed. And it wouldn't matter if the choice was performed earlier anyway. Because, as I say, there is no reference frame in which the predicted quantum expectation value changes. SR is never a factor, neither is order.

The question is not concerned about expectation value of any observable at all. It is asking: given the state of spin 1 to be up, how much time do we have to measure spin 2 and find it in state down, if spin 1 & 2 were initially entangled? Clearly, it is a question about the behaviour of conditional probability of the states w.r.t time; for which you must specify an observer, otherwise the question is ill-defined, as each observer have access to different set of knowledge (e.g. Wigner friend paradox). Entanglement itself is not a property defined w.r.t time, yes, but probabilities are.

@Paradoxy As I said, time/reference frame/SR is not an issue. No observer reports any different outcome due to order or reference frame. So yes, you can specify an observer - it simply makes no difference to the conditional probability (which to me is the quantum expectation value). It is the combined results of 2 measurements that any experimenter is interested in.
